# Copy, elaborate and delete files in a directory. Which php iteration to use?

Tags: php

I admit, as a newbie I'm really confused on how to code an iterative process for the following operations.

Scenery: my file test.php checks the oldest .txt file in a specific directory and copies it into another directory called "backup". After this, the same file is elaborated by "elab.php" (updates a MySQL database with some data contained in the file) and successively delete it, after a sleep time of 4 seconds.

Here is the code:

```
 $files = glob( '*.txt' );

 array_multisort(
 array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),
 SORT_NUMERIC,
 SORT_ASC,
 $files
 );

 $filename="$files[0]";

 copy($filename,"./backup/$filename");  
 echo "<b> $filename </b>copied<br>";   

 include ("/home/mysite/directory/elab.php");

 sleep(4);

 unlink($filename);
```

As in the directory there is more than one .txt file, i'd like to perform a recursive process. It should repeat the operation for all .txt files until the directory becomes empty. How to do?
I'm confused because i don't know if it is better to use "foreach" or "if" or "while". Which is the best one? How to modify the file with the recursive check?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files = scandir('folder/');
foreach($files as $file) {
  //do your work here
}
```

or

```
$files = glob('folder/*.{txt}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
  //do your work here
}
```

Comment: Hi xholicka i used your 2nd code and it works partially well. The 1st .txt file is elaborated, ok. when the process passes to another file i read the following error: "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare readfiletxt() (previously declared in /home/mysite/directory/elab.php:39) in /home/mysite/directory/elab.php on line 205 How to fix it?Thanks in advance,

Comment: from the error reported u are tryin to redeclare something what is not allowed to.

Comment: i suspect, that u try to redeclare function "readfiletxt()" in elab.php called in foreach cycle

Comment: I wonder why if i "recall" with my browser the test.php file (without foreach iteration) all works fine, even when i reload the file several times in a row. With the "foreach" construct it works ok only for the 1st file and the second not :/

Comment: post here your lines of code close to foreach cycle and the elab.php file content...otherwise we wont be able to help

Comment: Here is the actual "text.php"

<?php

$files = glob( '*.txt' );

array_multisort(
array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),
SORT_NUMERIC,
SORT_ASC,
$files
);

$filename="$files[0]";
foreach($files as $filename) {

copy($filename,"./backup/$filename"); 
echo "<b> $filename </b>copied<br>"; 
include ("/home/mysite/directory/elab.php");

sleep(4);

unlink($filename);
}
?>

Comment: The "elab.php" is very long. 
Anyway this is the readfiletxt function line:


......
  function readfiletxt ($string, &$date, &$name, &$surname)
 {
  $string = strtoupper ($string);

  // Read prefix
  if ($s = stristr($string,"<PREFIX"))
  {
   $values = sscanf ($s, "<PREFIX:%d>%[^'<'' ']", $length,$date['PREFIX']);
   if ($values != 2)....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18400/discussion-between-mattew-and-xholicka)

Answer (score 1):

`glob` has its own Iterator which is `GlobIterator` , I also guess you also want to group your backup base on dates.

```
$backup = __DIR__ . "/backups/" . date("Y-m-d");

if (! is_dir($backup))
    mkdir($backup) or trigger_error("Can't create directory");

$files = new GlobIterator(__DIR__ . "/test/*.txt");

foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    copy($file, $backup . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->getFilename()); //copy file
    printf("<b>%s</b>copied<br>", $file->getFilename());
    unlink($file); //delete file
}
```