# Checking for string within a directory of files but not including subdirectories

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to write a program that will open up a directory (in this case: files/), scan all of the filenames (not including any directories or ".." or ".") within this directory, and search for the filenames in the specified files from the "pages" array. If the filename is NOT found in the pages, the file will be moved to "unused-content".

My current code does not work. How can I achieve this goal?

```
<?php

if($handle = opendir('files/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $file_names[] = $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

$pages = array("page1.html","page2.shtml","page_three.shtml","page4.htm","page5.shtml");

for($x=0; $x<sizeOf($pages); $x++) {
  $current_page = file_get_contents($pages[$x]);
    for($i=0; $i<sizeOf($file_names); $i++) {
        if(!strpos($current_page,$file_names[$i])) {
            if (copy("files/".$file_names[$i],"files/unused-content/".$file_names[$i])) {
                unlink("files/".$file_names[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: instead of that while/array business, just use [glob()](http://php.net/glob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all that long code .. all you need is `FilesystemIterator`

```
$pages = array("1.xml","page2.shtml","page_three.shtml","page4.htm","page5.shtml");
$dir = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach ( $dir as $file ) {
    if ($file->isFile() && in_array(strlen($file->getFilename()), $pages)) {
        // copy
        // unlink
    }
}
```

[See another example using GlobIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13009129/1226894)

Comment: so the copy/unlink should be something like this?
            if (copy("files/".$file,"unused-content/".$file)) {
                unlink("files/".$file);
            }

thanks!

Comment: all you need is `copy($file,"unused-content/" . $file->getFilename());`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
<?php

if($handle = opendir('files/')) {
  $i=0;
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $file_names[$i] = $entry;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

$pages = array("page1.html","page2.shtml","page_three.shtml","page4.htm","page5.shtml");

for($x=0; $x<sizeOf($pages); $x++) {
  $current_page = file_get_contents($pages[$x]);
    for($i=0; $i<sizeOf($file_names); $i++) {
        if(!strpos($current_page,$file_names[$i])) {
            if (copy("files/".$file_names[$i],"files/unused-content/".$file_names[$i])) {
                unlink("files/".$file_names[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```